# Should users with many down-votes on a meta site be banned from asking questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, down-votes

When a user (on a regular *or* a Meta site) gets a particularly high number of downvotes, it seems an automatic filter kicks in which bans them from asking any more questions, with the message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998)] to learn more.

This makes sense for regular sites, as many downvotes would generally indicate *particularly bad* questions, potentially 'poisoning' the site and reducing its quality.  However, for *Meta* sites, the downvote is used to indicate mere disagreement with a question asked.  Surely it doesn't make sense to ban a user because they asked several (appropriate) questions, or made several (appropriate) proposals, with which many people disagreed?  Shouldn't this auto-filter be disabled for Meta sites?

Answer (score 6):

Ah, good point -- I never meant for this to be enabled on linked (child) metas. Disabling that now.

(However, I don't think this was actually *enabled* here -- were you seeing it on English?)

Comment: It was (and is) enabled on the main Meta; is there a different policy there to here?

Comment: @jez yes, it is enabled intentionally on [metase]

Comment: Why is the policy different?

Comment: @jez for historical reasons. If you are curious, hours of reading awaits you at [metase]

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to change that policy?  Someone can't file bug reports if they made a few unpopular suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

On a [similar question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well), asked on October, Jeff Atwood replied saying:

> Probably it will be enabled, with a relaxed threshold.

I agree that down-voting on a meta site has a different meaning than in the main site, but I still think that if a user keeps getting down-votes on questions, then that user is probably making poor suggestions.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Meta downvotes get used a lot against users that others "don't like", or even "for the lulz".  As long as they're being abused in this way, I don't think it makes sense to have the filter at all.  In fact, why does one need downvotes?  If it's an unpopular question, it can just be left at zero; if it's a dupe or there's something fundamentally wrong with it, people can vote to close.  Downvotes seem redundant to me.

Comment: @Jez I don't think there is a difference between down-voting a question on the main or the meta site, now that it changed who is influenced by the down-vote. If it would be possible to down-vote a bad proposal, then you should up-vote all the proposals that are not bad. The actual voting system allow three states; the questions with no votes are in the middle: they are not so good, but they are not bad too.

Comment: @jez that's a really broad accusation to make, and having been on meta.so for hundreds of days in a row -- I can't say I agree. I have seen *trolls* get systematically voted down, and I have seen "not this topic for the hundredth time again" posts get voted down, but I can't recall the behavior you are describing. Can you provide citations or evidence to support your position?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93910/if-voting-means-i-agree-disagree-on-meta-it-shouldnt-affect-reputation "You realize that, just by posting this question, you will get a lot of downvotes from people who are trying to be ironic/funny."